# What does TOP 1 mean in an sql query?

Tags: sql-server

What does TOP 1 mean in an sql query?

```
SELECT TOP 1 RequestId 
FROM PublisherRequests
```

Comment: It means take only the first n rows. You need an "order by" to define what the first rows will be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The query in the example will return the first `RequestID` from the table `PublisherRequests`.
The order of the results without an `Order By` clause is arbitrary.  So, your example will return an arbitrary `RequestID` (i.e. the first `RequestID` in an arbitrarily ordered list of `RequestID`s).
You can change the order by defining an `Order By`.
For example, to get the last entered ID, you can write

```
Select Top 1 RequestID
From PublisherRequests
Order By RequestID Desc
```

*Updated to include corrected order information from [@Kirtan Gor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882195/what-does-top-1-mean-in-an-sql-query/882202#882202) and [@AlexK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882195/what-does-top-1-mean-in-an-sql-query/882690#882690)*

Answer (score 17):

I disagree with "The order will be defined based on the clustered key in that table."

[SQL Server Books Online is quite explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):
If the query has no ORDER BY clause, the order of the rows is arbitrary

a repro demonstrating that this is not always the case: [Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order.](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx)

Comment: +1. Saw the link you posted. Thanks for the info. Answer updated.

Answer (score 10):

It will select the first row from the `PublisherRequests` table.

EDIT: [The order will be defined based on the clustered key in that table - This statement is incorrect]. Actually, according to Alex's findings, and according to BOL, the order of the rows will be arbitrary.

Reference can be found [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx).

Comment: not necessarily true. I posted a repro demonstrating that this is not always the case:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx

Comment: Also see Conor Cunningham's (MS Query Optimisation Team) blog entry on the same topic

http://blogs.msdn.com/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The TOP can be used to return as many rows as necessary, or a percentage of the total rows included - for more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It means only return the top 1 row, i.e. the first row.

Answer (score 0):

It limits the number of rows returned from the query to just 1. Its the same as Limit 1 in MySQL.