# How can I reverse the default ordering in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

In MySQL, when you execute a select SQL statement, there is a default ordering if you don't include a sorting clause. How can I reverse the default ordering? Just add `DESC`?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order/1793162#1793162

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default ordering" so you cannot "reverse" it.

Answer (score 7):

You can set a counter in your result fields and sort using it:

```
SELECT *, @counter := @counter + 1 AS 'counter' FROM tableName, (SELECT @counter := 0) r ORDER BY counter DESC
```

I think it will work as you want.

Comment: YES !! it works ! Thanks ! You answered perfectly to the question.

Comment: @Jerry But this is just the reverse of whatever order the rows were retrieved in, which doesn't have any guaranteed connection to the implementation order, which in turn has no guarantee to be anything in particular. If you want an order guaranteed, it has to be in the data. *Also* there are no guarantees for queries that both set & read a variable, so this query has undefined behaviour. For *a certain recent build* of 5.7 people at Percona who looked at the implementation saw that certain use of variables in `case` expressions (*not* like this) gives certain predictable behaviour. Until.

Answer (score 5):

If you want the data to come out consistently ordered, you have to use `ORDER BY` followed by the column(s) you want to order the query by.  `ASC` is the default, so you don't need to specify it.  IE:

```
ORDER BY your_column
```

...is the equivalent to:

```
ORDER BY your_column ASC
```

ASC/DESC is on a per column basis.  For example:

```
ORDER BY first_column, second_column DESC
```

...means that the query will sort the resultset as a combination using the `first_column` in ascending order, `second_column` in descending order.

Comment: The order I need is the reverse order in which the rows were inserted. "First inserted, first out".

Comment: @Steven: You'll have to provide the output of `DESCRIBE [your table name here]` from your database before I can suggest what to use.  If you have an autonumber primary key column - order by it `ASC`.  Next best thing would be a date_created column, using the datetime datatype.  Again, `ASC`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no guaranteed order if you don't specify an ORDER BY clause, thus the 'reverse of the default order' is undefined.

Comment: For those who prefer answers with evidence to back up the claims made: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better served by specifying the order you actually want. Tables, by their nature, have no order. It is probably just displayed in the order in which the rows were inserted - though there's no guarantee it will stay in that order.

Chances are, you probably just want to add this:

```
ORDER BY id DESC
```

...since most of the time, people use an auto-incrementing field called "id"

Comment: But what a pity,  there is no "Id" field in the table.

Comment: But if there is no Id field, or equivalent, is the order meaningful?

Comment: I think the default order in which the rows were inserted, the default order is "First inserted, last out". I want to change it to "First inserted, first out".

Comment: If there is no logical timestamp nor some kind of increment field, then you have insufficient information available to determine the historic order of inserts.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can specify a column name in an `ORDER BY` clause, you can't use `DESC`, and you'll have to resort to tricks involving `LIMIT` to see the last few records.

This would be unsatisfactory, I think.