# ORDER BY ignored when INSERTing into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, sql-insert

I just upgraded a MySQL 5.0 server to MySQL 5.5 and found that stored routines that worked before had broken. Difference: MySQL 5.5 seems to `INSERT` rows in an arbitrary order. So in the following code the `ORDER BY` clause has no effect. AFAIK, it used to have that in MySQL 5.0.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT * FROM MyOtherTable ORDER BY Col1, Col2 DESC;
```

People say that, by definition, [order is irrelevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950315/row-order-when-inserting-multplie-rows-in-mysql) in `INSERT`s: Just use `ORDER BY` when using `SELECT` from the table. Problem is I use a cursor to loop the table and perform complex operations. Surely I can put the `ORDER BY` statement on the cursor definition instead:

```
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Col1, Col2 DESC;
```

But that slows down the routine: from 10 seconds on MySQL 5.0 to over 10 minutes on MySQL 5.5.

Any ideas on how to solve problem?

Comment: You show us an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement but yet you claim you are using a cursor. Which is true? When using `insert ... select` it does not make any sense to use an `order by`. Why do you need an order by when using a cursor?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I use a cursor on `MyTable` which got its data from a `SELECT` with `ORDER BY`. So both are true.

Comment: So in fact you are **not** using `insert .. select`. But why do you (think) you need that order by?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The order is crucial because I implement  [maxim1000's algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212593/finding-overlapping-intervals-when-overlaps-are-rare]) in SQL, which has to do with finding overlapping intervals. It is more like procedural code, with regular SQL throwed in here and there to handle sets. It's very handy to avoid using a procedural langugage since the data originates from the database, and the output is to be stored in the same database.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: I do use `INSERT...SELECT`: `INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM MyOtherTable ORDER BY Col1, Col2 DESC;` And then the cursor: `DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM MyTable`.

Comment: Remove the `order by` from the first step. It's totally useless.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, I've understood that. Oddly, it did have effect in MySQL 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index on `(Col1, Col2)` to speed up ordering.

Comment: Good idea. I added an index for the relevant columns, but saw only marginal effect on performance. The difference from using a cursor without `ORDER BY` is striking.

Comment: I have to give you more credit. The routine is actually runnable now.