# What is auto_increment fields values order for MySQL INSERT .. SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, auto-increment, bulkinsert

Lets say we have next table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_insert_order (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

With some data like

```
INSERT INTO test_insert_order (parent_id, name) VALUES (1, 'a'),(1, 'b'),(1,'c'),(2,'b'),(2,'d'),(2,'a'),(3,'d'),(3,'a'),(4,'aa'),(5,'bb'),(6,'a'),(3,'a'),(1,'d'),(2,'c');
```

If we do

```
INSERT INTO test_insert_order (parent_id, name) SELECT 7, `name` FROM test_insert_order WHERE parent_id = 2 ORDER BY id;
```

Can we assume that new auto_generated ids will be in the same order as ids in result of select

```
SELECT id, 7, `name` FROM test_insert_order WHERE parent_id = 2 ORDER BY id;
```

So in result next query a.name will always match b.name

```
SET @i:=0;set @j:=0;
SELECT a.id, a.parent_id, a.name, a.order_id, b.id, b.parent_id, b.name, b.order_id FROM
  (SELECT *, @j:=@j+1 as order_id FROM test_insert_order WHERE parent_id = 2 ORDER BY id) a,
  (SELECT *, @i:=@i+1 as order_id FROM test_insert_order WHERE parent_id = 7 ORDER BY id) b
WHERE a.order_id = b.order_id;
```

I have made a few tests with concurrent treads and it is always true. But I can not find anything in MySQL docs about this situation.

UPDATE:
I guess this could be not true in some cluster solutions when a few instances have own pattern for autoincrement value, and one is lagging behind and query execution get distributed between then some how. But I do not have environment to check this.

Comment: Based on [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950315/row-order-when-inserting-multplie-rows-in-mysql) the order of rows inserted matches the order of rows encountered in the select query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
So you are saying that 
```
INSERT .. SELECT .. ORDER BY...;
```
is equivalent of
```
INSERT ... SELECT .... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 0, 1;
INSERT ... SELECT .... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1,1 ;
...
INSERT ... SELECT .... ORDER BY ... LIMIT n-1,1 ;
```
Do you have any notes about that from MySQL docs?

Comment: I don't know of a doc reference, but I have never known anything else to be true.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just worry, because I have found many stack overflow answers stating that order by does not matter  for INSERT ... SELECT statement, but non of them was about auto_increment field. Any way thank  you for your comment.

Comment: Yes, it matters, but then again you are already using `ORDER BY`, so I didn't bother to comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I will answer my own question.

I guess in most situations this will be true, but I was able to find cases when this algorithm could cause problem. First is mentioned in my UPDATE to the question regarding clusters solutions. Second, I can imagine is situation when table has gaps in id - auto_increment field (initially started from 1000000 not 0) and during execution of insert statement auto_increment value manually changed to lower value. So this will break auto_increment pattern.
I would suggest instead use order by some meaningful fields that we can predict uniqueness. If there are non, then there are not difference which from 2 identical record that was just inserted to use.

Regarding question from title. Auto_increment values in single bulk insert in single MySQL instance usually will be in growing order, but there are cases when it could be interrupted with auto_increment value changed to lower. On cluster solution it depend on cluster implementation, and most likely will be not predictable too.