# how to resolve this - group by changes the Order of items in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL server 2014,I'm fetching data from a view.The order of items is getting changed once i use **Group by** ,how can i get the order back after using this Group by,There is one date column,but its not saving any time,So i can't sort it based on date also..
How can I display the data in the same order as it displayed before using Group by?Anyone have any idea please help?

Thanks

Comment: I can suggest adding a column row_id based on the order before the group by and then ordering it by it after the group by

Comment: @sagi Adding a new row_id column is not necessary. If you already know the order based on which id's would be set for the `row_id` column, you can use those (and additional conditions) in your explicit `ORDER BY`. And that's enough to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables and views are essentially unordered sets. To get rows in a specific order, you should always add an `ORDER BY` clause on the columns you wish to order on.

I'm assuming you previously selected from the `VIEW` without an `ORDER BY` clause. The order in which rows are returned from a `SELECT` statement **without** an `ORDER BY` statement is **undefined**. The order you are getting them in, can change due to any number of reasons (eg some are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21371444/243373)).

Your problem stems from the mistake you made on relying on the order from a `SELECT` from a `VIEW` without an `ORDER BY`. You should have had an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT` statement to begin with.

---

> How can I display the data in the same order as it displayed before using Group by?

The answer: You can't if your initial statement did not have an `ORDER BY` clause.

The resolution: Determine the order you want the resultset in and add an `ORDER BY` clause on those columns, both in your initial query and the version with the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can enforce a specific order is to explicitly use a `ORDER BY` clause. Otherwise the order of rows is not guaranteed ([take a look at this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx) for more details) and the database engine will return the rows based on "as fast as it can" or "as fast as it can retrieve them from disk" rule. So, order can also vary between executions of the same query in the span of a few seconds.

When doing a `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`, SQL Server automatically does a `SORT` of the data based on an index it uses for that query.

Looking at the execution plan of your query will show you what index (and implicitly columns in that index) is being used to sort the data.

Comment: Correction: The only way you can enforce a specific order is to explicitly use a `ORDER BY`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thank you, I was thinking of ORDER BY but wrote GROUP BY

Comment: that auto sort spoils my row order, sad :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the row_number() function without any OVER and ORDER BY keywords? This should be done in a sub-select and when you group the data in the outer SELECT, use the AVG() function on the numbered column and ORDER the result by this. The problem is, that when you group rows, the original rows disappear. That's kind if the purpose of GROUP BY. ;) Depending on what you GROUP BY, what you're asking might be logically impossible.

EDIT:
Found this solution Googling: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/05/05/sql-server-generating-row-number-without-ordering-any-columns/

So you can number rows like this to maintain the order of rows from the table before you GROUP BY:

```
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
```