# How can I preserve one of my tables ordering when I query to join it with another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.18. I have one table which will be called *tblOriginal* for this example, and another table called *tblChanges*.

*tblOriginal* has the fields:

```
ID(VarChar 255), Description(VarChar 2056), Severity (SmallInt)
```

*tblChanges* has the fields:

```
ID(VarChar 255), NewSev(SmallInt)
```

*tblOriginal* has all the values filled out, and there are 150 entries. *tblChanges* has a subset of *tblOriginal*, at 50 entries, and all of the severity velues for this table are different. I want to import these changes into the *tblOriginal* without reordering the *tblOriginal* table.

Comment: In tblChanges do you ever repeat the same ID?  That is, do you need to make sure you only take the 'latest' update to sync with the original?

Answer (score 0):

Tables are unordered sets. So don't worry for change the ordering of tblOriginal table.

So just a simple update

```
UPDATE tblOriginal 
SET Severity = NewSev
FROM tblChanges 
WHERE tblOriginal.ID = tblChanges.ID
```

Comment: The preserving of the order for the table is important, and running a query that just selects all entries for the table changes after running this command. It re-orders some of the entries.

Comment: As I told you, tables are unordered sets, so even when now you have the order you `'want'` that isn't a guarante. If you want show the data in any order you need to use `ORDER BY`. Check [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371176/unordered-results-in-sql) for more info

Comment: I have solved this problem by using the following statement.

`ALTER TABLE tblOriginal ADD COLUMN key_column BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;`.

Which I then used an 

`SELECT * from tblOriginal ORDER BY key_column;`

Comment: Good for you, but that is a very different issue. Still even when you get the order by the auto generated Primary Key, order isn't  guaranteed on all cases as I already show you on the link above. So be careful with this.

Comment: How can I serialize the rows to be in the same order reliably?

Comment: only by using `ORDER BY`, even when engine try to put everything order by the Primary Key, you can have other index on your table, the data can be split between different blocks or a multithread process can access data in sevral call and then build a result. So unless you specify the order, there isnt guaranteed