# T-SQL round down to 2 decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a numeric column, and each number has at least 5 decimals. The examples are in below.

How to round the column off to 2 decimals, while maintaining the sum of the first 3 numbers and sum of the last two numbers equal to 100.00 in SQL Server?

```
Numbers
22.41489
57.34326
20.24185
73.50463
26.49537
```

I have tested some sql. For example,

```
select cast(round('22.41489',2) as decimal(18,2)) as a, cast(round('57.34326',2) as decimal(18,2)) as b
,cast(round('20.24185',2) as decimal(18,2)) as c, cast(round('73.50463',2) as decimal(18,2))  as d 
, cast(round('26.49537',2) as decimal(18,2)) as e
```

The sum of a, b, c will be 99.99. Since all the numbers are in the same column, I need to apply the same transformation to all the numbers. I cannot use transformation 1 for the first 3 numbers and apply transformation 2 for the last 2 numbers.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest doing the math and casting the result as decimal(2).

Comment: Is there some other column (e.g. `Group`) that controls which records are supposed to add up to 100.00? Asking because records in a table are considered to be [unordered sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371176/unordered-results-in-sql), so without that other column or an `order by` on the `select` query these numbers could show up in a different order next time you look for the same records.

Comment: @tarheel Yes. There is another ID column. Certain numbers use the same ID. In this case, the first three numbers use the same ID "A", and the last two numbers use the same ID "B".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Window Functions to add the missing portion to the number that lost the most during rounding. Like this:

```
declare @T table (grp int, num numeric(10,5))
insert into @T (grp, num) values
(1, 22.41489),
(1, 57.34326),
(1, 20.24185),
(2, 73.50463),
(2, 26.49537)

select
    grp,
    num as original_number,
    round(num, 2) + 
    case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by grp order by num - round(num, 2) desc)
    then (100 - sum(round(num, 2)) over (partition by grp))
    else 0
    end as modified_number  
from @T
```

**Results**

```
1   22.41489    22.42000
1   57.34326    57.34000
1   20.24185    20.24000
2   73.50463    73.50000
2   26.49537    26.50000
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! I didn't know it would be so complicated.

Comment: Upvoting this as I admire it's ingenuity and taught me something I didn't consider or think was possible. But from a maintainability standpoint if you asked me to code review this, it's no way I would approve it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [round()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_round.asp) function , even after sum

look at this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/18832)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to round your numbers down to 2 decimal places but you still want the sum to be the same. That's not going to always hold true. For example, if I add these 5 numbers:

```
 (1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2)
```

I will get 6, but if I round all the numbers first, then take the sum:

```
 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
```

I will get 5. This is not a limitation in SQL Server, this is just mathematics.

For your business case I would see if you can "round" and "sum" the numbers on whatever front end you are using (e.g. Reporting Services, Excel, etc) where it has the freedom to truncate decimal places while maintaining the precision behind the scenes if you do aggregate the values.

If that's not an option, return both the rounded/formatted value and the full precision value. Use the rounded/formatted value for UI/Display purposes, and use the full precision value for further aggregation.

```
CREATE TABLE NumberTable
(
    Number numeric(10,5)
);

INSERT INTO NumberTable
VALUES
 (22.41489),
 (57.34326),
 (20.24185),
 (73.50463),
 (26.49537);

SELECT Number,
    Cast(Round(Number*100,0)/100.00 as numeric(5,2)) RoundedNumber,
    Format(Number,'0.00') FormattedNumber
FROM NumberTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes. It is a mathematics issue and business case. Unfortunately, the whole reporting process will be submitted through SQL Server. I was planning to "solve" this using a special note to explain. I just want to know whether this can be done in SQL or not.