# How to get First not zero value in table column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample table below. From that table #A I need the as shown below. Basically I wanted to get the data from first not zero row. If after that any zero occurs no issue on that.

```
CREATE TABLE #A
(
    [Data] int
)

INSERT INTO #A 
VALUES (0), (0), (0), (0), (0),
       (23), (524), (723), (0), (89),
       (23), (4), (51), (0), (0)

SELECT * FROM #A
```

Required output :

```
Data
-------
 23
524
723
  0
 89
 23
  4
 51
  0
  0
```

I tried below script but my data column itself getting sorted. Which is not working properly.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY data) Rn
     FROM
         #A) t
```

Comment: Your data has no column that denotes the order of it. Without a way to order your data, your requirement is impossible.

Comment: @Larnu I've given my column as data just for the example purpose.

Comment: That doesn't change my point. With 1 column what you want is impossible.

Comment: Data in a table is unordered. You show 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 524, but that's the same table as 0, 0, 524, 0, 0, 23, 0 or any other order. This is what Larnu is talking about. Your tasks refers to an order that does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Larnu mentioned:  Without a proper sequence, there is NO GTD of the desired order.

Take a peek at [Unordered results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371176/unordered-results-in-sql)

Notice I added an ID which could be an IDENTITY or even a datetime stamp

**Example**

```
Create table #A
                (
                  id int,[Data] int
                )

                insert into #A values(1,0),
                                     (2,0),
                                     (3,0),
                                     (4,0),
                                     (5,0),
                                     (6,23),
                                     (7,524),
                                     (8,723),
                                     (9,0),
                                     (10,89),
                                     (11,23),
                                     (12,4),
                                     (13,51),
                                     (14,0),
                                     (15,0)
```

**Option 1:**

```
Select *
 From  #A
 Where ID>= (Select top 1 id From  #A where data<>0 Order By ID )
 Order by ID
```

**Option 2:**

```
Select id
      ,data
 From (
         Select * 
               ,Flg = sum(case when Data<>0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id)
          from #A
      ) A
 Where Flg>0 
 Order By ID
```

**Results**

```
id  data
6   23
7   524
8   723
9   0
10  89
11  23
12  4
13  51
14  0
15  0
```