# SQL: join the order looks different

Tags: sql, join

I have table test

```
create table test (col_value int);
insert into test values(1);
insert into test values(2);
insert into test values(3);
insert into test values(4);
```

and it looks like

```
col_value
1
2
3
4
```

Now when i am trying to run the join and check the final table

```
select * from test a left join test b ON a.col_value < b.col_value;
```

```
a col_value | b col_value 
1         | 2         
1         | 3         
2         | 3         
1         | 4         
2         | 4         
3         | 4         
4         | (null)
```

What i was expecting is its ordered as per the a col_value as below.

```
a col_value |b col_value 
1         | 2         
1         | 3                
1         | 4
2         | 3           
2         | 4         
3         | 4         
4         | (null)
```

Comment: without an explicit ORDER BY, ordering of rows is not guaranteed

Comment: any table in SQL should be considered unordered. never rely on some assumed order to be in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single query, run several times (perhaps over time) can return results in different orders. UNLESS you specify a specific order using the `order by` clause.

See previous question: [Unordered results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371176/unordered-results-in-sql/21371731#21371731)

Blog covering this topic (and others) https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ORDER BY`. Generally, it is recommended to order the result in the presentation level if possible:

```
select * 
from test a 
left join test b 
ON a.col_value < b.col_value
order by a.col_value, b.col_value
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of rows in a SQL result set is not guaranteed--if you need a result set in a particular order, you need to use an ORDER BY statement.

In practice, you may have seen the records in numeric order when you did a SELECT from the table because the data was read as a single block from storage in that order.