# How select query retrieves data internally?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql memory table with contains priorities assign to each row.I am creating this table every 2 minutes and this table is being called almost 100 times/second.

It contains around 800 rows.

Query I am running is like:

```
select * from table order by priority limit 0,20
```

I want to optimize this query.Can I put the data in the sorted order while creating the table and can assume data pulled will always be sorted based on priority if I remove `the order by` clause.

Thanks

Comment: What do you use to work with database? Php?

Comment: yes..I use php to connect to mysql..

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions:

1. If you create this table and do NOT modify after creation it then after creating and filling do this `ALTER TABLE table ORDER BY priority`. This will sort your table and you can give up your ordering.
2. Don't use mysql to order your results. Use [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) for it.

Also dont forget about indexes. If you didn't turn off mysql result caching then all your selects are cached and don't calculates results. So you have to check your config for it. Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html)

Comment: I guess.we cant reply on insertion order in select query.please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949641/mysql-row-order-for-select-from-table-name

Comment: Yes, my suggestion is to alter table after insertion, and assuming that you will not modify it after alter.

Comment: problem is this doesn't work if I have where conditions.And my data is index on other columns as well..

Comment: Then query cache to your help or use memcached for caching.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you can do database-side & 1 on the actual HTML/PHP side to optimise this query:

1. Use an ISAM table with 'priority' indexed @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html & also make it as small as possible e.g. 'priority' SMALLINT(3) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL .
   The last point, limiting, you've already got.
2. Use an opcode cacher to cache the results and deliver them directly to people's browsers if the information is only changing every-so-often, without requerying the database e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators