# Get entries in order they were inserted without a primary key?

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if it is possible to query any database entries in order they were inserted without a primary key?

Is there a specification in the SQL which order the entries have on a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not. There is no way to guarantee the row order of the records. You must use `ORDER BY`.

See [MySQL row order for "SELECT * FROM table_name;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949641/mysql-row-order-for-select-from-table-name)

Comment: Thank you for the claryfication

Comment: @schlimpf . . . To emphasize, in SQL, tables are inherently unordered.  Remember, relational databases are based on sets, not tables, and sets do not have an ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying `ORDER BY`, there is no guarantee that your columns will be returned in any particular order -- you should consider it to be random.  The order depends on the engine; with MyISAM they will be returned in INSERT order unless there have been updates/deletes.  With InnoDB, they will be ordered by the primary key.

If you want your columns to be sorted in a particular order, include an ordinal column / timestamp in the table definition and `ORDER BY` that.