# Make query to copy everything from one table to another one ORDERING BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm curious how to create `table2` of the same structure with the same data as `table1`, but with order by the column frequency.

Or, the equivalent of this problem is: to change the id of rows in the table properly.

It doesn't matter, whether by ASC, or DESC.

As result, the `table1`:

```
**id - name - frequency**

    1 - John - 33
    2 - Paul - 127
    3 - Andy - 74
```

Should become `table2`:

```
**id - name - frequency**

    1 - Paul - 127
    2 - Andy - 74
    3 - John - 33
```

What's the shortest way to do that?

Also, I would be interesting in the query that's fastest for huge tables (although performance is not so important for me).

Comment: `SELECT * INTO Table2 FROM Table1 ORDER BY column`

Comment: @David Starkey :  error #1327 - Undeclared variable: Table2

Comment: Nevermind.  `SELECT INTO` is not available for mysql.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to create the new id.  Here is a MySQL way to do it:

```
create table table2 as
    select @rn := @rn + 1 as id, name, frequency
    from table1 cross join (select @rn := 0) const
    order by frequency desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
CREATE TABLE b SELECT col FROM a ORDER BY col
```

Be aware, there is [no way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1949663/679449) to guarantee row order in a database (other than physically). You must always use an `ORDER BY`.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html)

Comment: Seems like there is no id column for that table.