# Select a row from MySQL table based on its order

Tags: mysql

I am trying to grab a specific row from a MySQL table based on its position. Let's say I have these records:

```
+-------------------+
|   ID   |   Data   |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Apple    |
|      2 | Orange   |
|      3 | Kiwi     |
|      4 | Lobster  |
|     25 | Chicken  |
|     26 | Banana   | <----
|     27 | Melon    |
+--------+----------+
```

Now, I want to grab the 6th record from this table, but I don't know what the `ID` is, or what the `Data` column contains. All I know is that it is the 6th record in the table. How would I go about this?

Comment: you cant, there's no internal 'order' in a db . anything that requires this means something else is fundamentally wrong

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm47360244378112

Comment: It's actually a whole lot more complicated than @Dagon's answer, but that sure is a sweet summary

Comment: well i was restricted on space, and the point is any code that 'needs' this is wrong wrong wrong

Comment: May I ask why you would ever need this?

Comment: I am building a info screen application. And it must know the index of the record. And not the ID. This is because it will cause trouble once i delete a record.

Comment: Why does everyone seem so hostile? Im not an expert in this... All i want is help. Sorry for asking.

Comment: you need to change how you do things so you have an id to use. there simply is no inherit order in the db

Comment: You don't know the ID, but you do know the value of `Data` column. Even though I don't see any reason why you ever would need this, you can do `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Data LIKE "Banana"`

Comment: Alright... Im not wasting my time here anymore. The application im writing does not require to know any values. All it does is read the database downwards, and it is using Index count to figure out what row it last was reading from. Why is that so hard to just take in? I am a total noob at MySQL and im sorry if this question was stupid and all. Anyway. I am not wasting my time here anymore. Asked a mod to delete this question.

Comment: sorry, you are missing the point, there is **no** inherit down or up, you MUST define that in the db structure yourself. As a self confessed "total noob" you should be more open to the advise of others

Comment: Sounds like @DJZorrow wants to grab the Xth row. This would have applications in selecting the Xth entry in a contest, etc. Yes, there 100% should be a column to store the order of insertion but this is a super simplified case. Don't take it personally, you gotta start somewhere, and every one of us was a noob at some point.

Comment: This is actually not a bad question per se, as almost all newbies fall into this fault of reasoning. I couldn't find an exact duplicate of this question. If there is none, I believe it should be reopened and a better answer which is actually correct is due, because all the rant in comments doesn't REALLY answer the question, just looks like chit-chat. The current closing reason is also wrong, as it is pretty clear what is asked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couldn't you use use the `LIMIT` clause:

```
SELECT ID, Data
  FROM TABLE
  LIMIT 5,1
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a12b8/1).

Comment: Thank you! Did the trick! I don't know why it was downvoted though? Is this bad practice or something?

Comment: yes it is bad practice, there is no guarantee this will work as you expect

Comment: Despite being a strange question, perhaps even flawed structure, @DJZarrow somehow knows (for now) the position of the record. He wants to grab a row based on when it was inserted into the table (more or less). In reality there should be an `ORDER BY` clause based on date, auto inc, or something to guarantee the order is truly the order of insertion. But we're glossing over a lot of things here, sooo....

Comment: DELETE the records 'Apple', 'Orange' and 'Kiwi' ... reinsert them with the same ID numbers ... now find 'Banana' - granted, you've answered the question but the question is ... weird ;)

Comment: Have a look at this answer to similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/1949663/3325500

Comment: This will work just fine for the application i am currently writing. It does not matter what data is there. But what does matter is that i keep track of the current row it is reading from. Its not more complicated than that. And this answer did just what i asked for. And besides: There is no security to worry about either if that is an issue. Because this will not run over the internet. Only LAN.

Comment: why not add a row field to the db then?

Comment: Ideally there would be a row field, date field or something to maintain insertion, or some other, order. Two lessons in one @DJZorrow :)

Comment: Alright people. Ive been using this answer in my software for the past month now. Everything works fine and as expected. Not a single crash or misbehavior. So why this is not an acceptable answer to you is a mindblowing mystery for me.