# get different result using select * and select askid

Tags: mysql, sql

That sounds wired,I find this occasionally when I try to optimize `limit`.

askid is **PK** and the table has **1.14M** rows.
I can not give the table because it's in production environment.

I try

`SELECT askid FROM ask limit 1000000,1;`

return **1001747**

Then I try

`SELECT * FROM ask limit 1000000,1;`

return **1000627**

askid has index and it influence the result, but I think the result should be same,isn't it?

`SELECT askid FROM ask ORDER BY askid LIMIT 1000000,1;`

return **1000627**.

But why `ORDER BY` matters?Is there something wrong with the askid index?

The performance is much different.
The first one takes **0.2s**;
the second takes **2s**;
the third one takes **1s**;
How to optimize it and get the right result?

The mysql version I use is **5.6.10**

Comment: Attempting to query using any positional clauses (ie `LIMIT`) is totally useless without `ORDER BY`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL row order for "SELECT \* FROM table\_name;"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949641/mysql-row-order-for-select-from-table-name)

Comment: @Phil But the performance is much different.The first one is at least 5 times faster than the third.Though the result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have an OFFSET set to `1000000`. Those queries are not the same. `*` `SELECT`s everything, not just your `PRIMARY KEY`. With the `,` after your `LIMIT` it becomes `LIMIT offset, limit`. Also, you should use `ORDER BY askid` on those queries so you have the correct order.

Comment: There is no rows existed without PK.Do you mean physical storage?I know little about this.... ....

Comment: Is `askid` defined as `PRIMARY KEY(askid)` when you created the table?

Answer (score 0):

SQL makes no guarantees in regards to row order, it chooses whatever makes for the best plan based on your query.

If you expect an order, specify it using `order by`. And you most definitely should if you're limiting your result set.

Answer (score 0):

Data is stored in the natural order.  This can be the order the rows are inserted or it can be the order the rows were updated, depending on the engine.  It is **NOT** the PK order.

When you do not specify `order by` you are getting the natural order (for all intents and purposes it is random).  You should not rely on it.

You can argue all you like, but you have already proved to yourself that the `order by` should be used.