# MySQL simple query of table returns results in strange order

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

My MySQL table is set up with an auto-incrementing primary key.  Whenever I

`SELECT * FROM [MYTABLE]`

The record with the highest primary key value is not displayed last.  Is there a reason for this?  I can

`SELECT * FROM [MYTABLE] ORDER BY [MYTABLE].ID ASC`

and the highest is displayed last.  Sorry, I am not at liberty to share anything from the database.  Perhaps there is some sort of underlying data field (like a record number) not contained in the table that is being used for the sort.  This is MySQL 5.7.19 on a Windows server.  <s>It seems to me that sorting by a primary key makes more sense than what it's doing.
MySQL version 5.7.19.</s>

Comment: Rows are not stored sorted, the only way to get a result sorted is to ORDER IT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is MySQL row order for "SELECT \* FROM table\_name;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949641/what-is-mysql-row-order-for-select-from-table-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not applicable.
Well, of course, MySquile inherently fetches data no matter how it is stored.
Sort the index table each time you change it, list the main key in the table, or sort the call each time.
select with ordering

```
SELECT * FROM [MYTABLE] ORDER BY [MYTABLE].ID ASC
```

Keep in mind that you can never guarantee the order of an auto-incremented column once you start inserting and removing data, so you shouldn't be relying on any order except that which you specify using ORDER BY in your queries. This is an expensive operation that you are doing, as it requires indexes to be completely re-created, so I wouldn't suggest doing it often.