# How to sort relational table without surrogate PK by insertion order?

Tags: sql, primary-key, surrogate-key

Say I have a `JOB` and `COMPANY` table and a third `JOB_COMPANY` table that relates the two in a many-to-many cardinality.

I've learnt that it's an anti-pattern for the `JOB_COMPANY` to have a surrogate `id` PK.
The PK should probably be a composite `(job_id,company_id)`.

In this case, following the best practice, how would I sort the `JOB_COMPANY` by insertion order (and `DESCENDING` also)?
Would this case justify a surrogate `id` PK?

Comment: What exactly is "insertion order"? Tables have no row order, result sets & windows have (partial) order per an ORDER BY. [What is MySQL row order for “SELECT * FROM table_name;”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1949641/3404097) 
[SQL best practice to deal with default sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1793147/3404097) PS 1 DBMS please. 1 question please.

Comment: Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & sometimes limited to titles, but read the help. Google re googling/searching, including in Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @philipxy I have the need to sort the rows of this relational table by the order they were inserted. In this case, what's the best practice?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. PS As the links I gave explain, there is no record of the order in which they were inserted, tables have no row order. PS Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. PS [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Answer (score 0):

So its not the end of the world having a surrogate key as a primary key, as long as it isn't a clustered primary key. You want your clustered index to be a composite key in majority of cases as it will usually be how your table is accessed most of the time so you will see performance gains. Unless however you have a table where the data is only accessed by ID, in that case the only choice for the clustered Primary key is ID. What you could have is:

```
Primary Key NonClustered - ID
Unique Clustered Index - job_id,company_id
OR
Primary Key Clustered - job_id,company_id
Unique NonClustered Index - ID
```

That way under the hood 2 indexes are created to be used. So you can seek to your data with both of the below predicates

```
WHERE ID = 
OR
WHERE job_id = 
AND company_id =
```