# how can I get query result order by desc with out "order by" command?

Tags: mysql

when I using select command without order by sub-command:

> select acolumn from table

The result sequence is order by id column asc as default( or in the sequence that the record was inserted into the table, I am not sure). but I want it order by desc without order by sub-command.

I tried create desc index on id column, it does not help.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "but I want it order by desc without order by" --- because... ?

Comment: I think NO there is no way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8746712/2236219

Comment: SQL tables are not ordered: if you don't use an ORDER BY there are no guarantees of the order in which the rows are returned. Just use an ORDER BY.

Answer (score 3):

No, that can't be done.

Your current query doesn't return the items ordered by any specific value or specifically in the order they were inserted, but in the order that is currently convenient for the database to fetch them. This order may change any time if the database decides on a different execution plan to fetch the data.

If you want a reliable ordering, you need to use the `order by` clause to specify it.

Comment: Technically mysql supports `ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY`, but one should understand that it will only work up to the next table modification.

Comment: @zerkms I tried this: alter table tablename order by id desc; it does not help. The case is I am reuse our framework to implement a function, it is not a official process, so I don't want to update the select command in the common framework, just want find a work around.

Comment: @waitsumme: well, you haven't explained why you need that. Without that you will not get a meaningful solution for your problem

Comment: @waitsummer: you're out of luck

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can try this if you are using phpmyadmin.