# SQL : What is a good column for indexing?

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, indexing

I'm using **MySQL** with **Django** framework.
(I have plan to change MySQL to **PostgreSQL** later)

Following is example case which abstracted real DB.

---

### Column description

1. **`ID`**(`int(11)` type) : auto-incremented value from 1
2. **`Column A`**(`int(10)` type) : choice from 10 values
3. **`Column B`**(`longtext` type): Text field

---

### Example of data row

```
ID     |    Column A    |      Column B
               ...
21     |    301010101   |  TGGQtY84r033i0F6tpx3...
22     |    301010102   |  31TfNgzpxkcuMLxrrZ6D...
23     |    301010103   |  U069Z5kG354BwDriFw6d...
24     |    301010107   |  d4MSkCBxwZzKusALQAIQ...
25     |    301010105   |  R1SJCWeM62P1ikQwmG3f...
26     |    301010103   |  bVScBZbf0n1tkdgFCwmD...
27     |    301010102   |  4UpQGyCz5KhlolEdsO8M...
28     |    301010101   |  x89gOjNS4J4xiP1DfIWH...
29     |    301010110   |  STMlfUwx8afCZBsa8CWJ...
30     |    301010101   |  XctEBThnlA5MYTKqycLJ...
31     |    301010104   |  fRAEBMXDEdNFn5aENn4r...
31     |    301010105   |  GlIwVjVF16WE4zWnnSy8...
               ...
```

1. **Many rows** (more than hundred thousands)
2. Each row have `Column A` value **among 10 values** (301010101, .., 301010110)

---

### Query usage

1. **Grouping by `Column A` first, then ordering by `ID` descendingly.**

   For example, `Models.object.filter(Column A = "301010101").order_by('-id')`

---

### Question

For above case, **what column** would be the **best for index** ?

1. **`ID`** as index (Default)
2. **`Column A`** as index
3. Using **`ID`** and **`Column A`** together as index (Multi-index)

---

### Edit : The result

I tested it with 500000 rows of random data. (with `ordering=['-id'] in Class Meta)

Then, I tested query `Models.objects.filter(Column A = "301010101")`

1. **`ID`** as index (Default) : 0.33 sec
2. Using **`ID`** and **`Column A`** together as index (Multi-index) : 0.12 sec

**From the above test result, I convinced that using `ID` and `Column A` together as Multi-index is the most optimized case.**

Comment: For your first condition a composed index on `(ColumnA,id)` would be helpful.Test it directly in mysql with EXPLAIN.But given the choices I would guess 2

Comment: I tested it by myself with 500000 random rows of data as you suggested. The result is, using `ID` and `Column A` together as index is the fastest case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that "specific" query, it appears that you'd have better performance on a dual-column index, as suggested, on (column a,id).

From the manual:

> "If a multiple-column index exists on col1 and col2, the appropriate
>   rows can be fetched directly. If separate single-column indexes exist
>   on col1 and col2, the optimizer attempts to use the Index Merge
>   optimization (see Section 8.3.1.4, “Index Merge Optimization”), or
>   attempts to find the most restrictive index by deciding which index
>   excludes more rows and using that index to fetch the rows"

Comment: wouldn't the index on  (column a,id) only be used (increase speed) when filtering by 'column a' and 'id'? i.e. `Models.object.filter(Column A = "301010101", id=12)`

Comment: it is my understanding that the "id" column is being used in that query via the "order by" clause

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a one more question. Assume case that table is already ordered by `-id` (`ordering=['-id;]` in Class Meta). In this case we don't have to query `order_by('-id')`. Then, single index as `Column A` is okay ?

Comment: that's a good question.  As for "good practice", I would personally never "assume" anything with the database.  If you are depending on the order of the table itself as the default "order by" when the desired "order by" is not included in the query would be an assumption, in this case.

The following link has some good discussion on the assumption of order-by-default:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries

Answer (score 0):

if the ID is an auto_increment column (which i think it should be); then it is already Indexed.

It would help with performance if you indexed `Column A` as well