# Is SELECT * deterministic?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a database interface and need the answer of the following question:

Will `SELECT * FROM some_table` always return the results in the same order in MySQL?

Comment: `SELECT *` is antipattern. In long run more problems than gains. What if in the future someone adds new column?

Comment: same column order, or row order?

Comment: If you mean the order of columns: yes. If you mean the order of rows: no. Except you add some `order by` clause, then the order of rows is always the same, too.

Comment: As long as you dont use order by clause

Comment: Relying on a specific column order opens your code to an obvious potential bug: if you alter the table you need to ensure that new columns are inserted in the expected location. DBAs will normally avoid that at any cost on very large data sets.

Answer (score -1):

By default it returns the order by primary_key(if you do not provide any order by clause)

Comment: That would be news to me?

Comment: Ah, it seems to be *sometimes* the case, but can't be relied upon. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries

Comment: I guess it can happen if query optimiser decides to fetch rows directly through an index. But SQL thumb rule is: avoid unnecessary expensive operations (such as sorting).