# MySQL incorrect ordering

Tags: mysql, docker, percona

I have a table for example: id | name | date_add

With content:

```
1| Mark | 2018-02-01 10:00:00

2| Andrew | 2018-02-01 10:00:00
```

When I try to do this request: `select * from table order by date_add`

I get rows in the next order: 2, 1

It occurs in Percona MySQL docker

With the same Percona on my host machine I got in 1, 2 order

How to enable logic in Docker as at my host machine?

Comment: The date is the same for both records... there is no ordering you can expect in that case. Add `Order BY date_add, id` instead if you need to insure the order when two dates are the same.

Comment: @JNevill Is there no default ordering by primary key?

Comment: Since in that case the `date_add` field is the same value, the ordering is somewhat arbitrary and may come out differently on a different implementation. What do you require? Do you require the `id` to be in ascending order if the `date_add` is the same? If so, just specify: `select * from table order by date_add, id`. There is no default ordering.

Comment: No. There is no default ordering in any RDBMS. It must always be specified.

Comment: It's strange why I've got this result in my docker but in another 3 host machine I've got another result.

Comment: @user3169724 this different results is strange, are the tables in the same engine (myisam, innodb) in all these hosts? Are you performing the queries direct throught the console or using a programming language like php, java?

Comment: @arturios I checked. Engines are the same. I did these requests in mysql terminal client. And responses are not the same. By the way, I did about 10 the same requests in docker and in 2 of 10 I've got rows in straight order : 1, 2

Comment: @arturios There is nothing strange here. The order is undefined beyond what the ORDER BY clause specifies. Any implementation is free to do whatever it likes.

Comment: @EJP when you mean any implementation you are refering to a fork of the source code? Or just a compilation/package to another architecture, system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless specified in and ORDER BY clause, row ordering is indeterminate. There is no default ordering (or sub-ordering) that you should expect to obtain.

In this case, you should specify an ordering clause:

```
ORDER BY date_add, id
```

This behavior may be influenced by Percona or Docker, but again, you should not expect any apparent "default" ordering to appear, even between queries made minutes apart. See also [What is the default Order By of queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519)