# What is the dafault ordering in Laravel Eloquent Model::all() function?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

In the Laravel Eloquent `Model::all()` function, what is the default ordering for the returned query? I ask this because I'm pretty sure it's in ascending order by primary key which defaults do `'id'` when you make the model through

```
php artisan make:model Model -m
```

However, when I call it like this:

```
return $users = User::all();
```

I get the following results in the browser:

[image: Eloquent all() function results]

The results seem to be in no particular order by any of the attributes.
I am fully aware I can order them by id by doing

```
return $users = User::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
```

But just a few days ago they were being ordered automatically. What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default sort order for laravel is simply nothing. It does not apply a default "ORDER BY" clause, which means that it follows PostgreSQL rules for unordered results. From some similar answers [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8746712/4875631):

> - Do not depend on order when ORDER BY is missing.
> - Always specify ORDER BY if you want a particular order -- in some situations the engine can eliminate the ORDER BY because of how it
>     does some other step.
> - GROUP BY forces ORDER BY. (This is a violation of the standard. It can be avoided by using ORDER BY NULL.)
>
> `SELECT * FROM tbl` -- this will do a "table scan". If the table has
>   never had any DELETEs/REPLACEs/UPDATEs, the records will happen to be
>   in the insertion order, hence what you observed.
>
> If you had done the same statement with an InnoDB table, they would
>   have been delivered in PRIMARY KEY order, not INSERT order. Again,
>   this is an artifact of the underlying implementation, not something to
>   depend on.

Comment: I see what you mean, I just happened to be getting "ordered results" until yes, I did began deleting and updating entries. Like you said, it is no longer dependable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With a great agreement with [FrankerZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4875631/frankerz)'s answer, I would like to add, whenever you wonder what query laravel is structuring under the ORM, DB listener will be quickest option to use :

```
<?php

\DB::listen(function($sql) {
    dump($sql);
});
```

W.r.t. this question it would give `select * from users` when you do `User::all()`.

Note: Check listen function as per the laravel version you are using, the parameter count are different in older and newer versions.

Reference : [Documentation Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#listening-for-query-events)

Comment: Very useful, I will give it a try!