# c# linq OrderByDescending with inner LastOrDefault

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

Is there a way to order, let's say, all customers by the date of the last purchase?

For example

```
ctx.Customers.OrderByDescending(e => e.Purchases.LastOrDefault().DateTime);
```

It would be something like this, however, this doesn't work. It throws the exception

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Purchase
LastOrDefault[Purchase]
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Purchase])'
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

edit:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Purchases = new List<Purchase>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual IList<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
}

public class Purchase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdCustomer { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

In Context I do have somthing like

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasRequired(s => s.Customer)
            .WithMany(p => p.Purchases)
            .HasForeignKey(s => s.IdCustomer);
}
```

Comment: Edit: Sorry, I typed wrong. The error persists even with LastOrDefault being method.

Comment: Can you show some code? The class holding the `Purchases` attribute and the class holding the `DateTime` attribute?

Comment: what is `e.Purchases`?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ its a IList of Purchase

Comment: @CorentinPane I could, the code I showed was supposed to work?

Comment: Change IList to ICollection<Purchase> and let me know if that helps

Comment: Please specify what orm and version you are using because it really important some things are not supported exactly in EF core.

Answer (score 2):

```
ctx.Customers.OrderByDescending(e => e.Purchases.LastOrDefault().DateTime);
```

looks like a context query (Entity Framework, usually dbContext), so here you have an IQueryable not a List.

Entity Framework will try to convert this to a SQL statement before giving you results, but

```
SELECT * BOTTOM(X) FROM TABLE ORDER BY Purchases desc
```

is not an expression, but more importantly EF just doesn't recognize what you want to do.

Instead, you just want to flip the logic to:

```
SELECT * TOP(X) FROM TABLE ORDER BY Purchases asc
```

Or:

```
ctx.Customers.OrderBy(e => e.Purchases.FirstOrDefault().DateTime);
```

or you can order by on your subquery:

```
ctx.Customers.OrderBy(e => e.Purchases.OrderByDescending(x => x.propertyToSortOn)
.FirstOrDefault().DateTime);
```

Getting the last n records from the bottom of a sorted list, is actually the same as getting the top n from a list sorted the other way:

1,2,3,4,5,6 -> top 3 in ascending order = 1,2,3

6,5,4,3,2,1 -> bottom 3 in descending order = 3,2,1

Comment: I am not sure about this. Are related enumerations ordered in EF? This could return a different row when you run a query multiple times depending on the SQL server don't know about MySQL.

Comment: [I might be right on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746519/sql-what-is-the-default-order-by-of-queries)

Comment: @FilipCordas You are right, but so is the code. You need to *always* specify the sort column. EF will try to guess the default, st least sometimes. But it isn't nearly reliable enough when you need to rely on it. Using the inner OrderByDescending as in the last example will translate in EF 6.x at least as an inner `Select * top(x) from t order by [ENTITY2].[X] desc` or similar.

Comment: Your answer is correct just thought it was worth mentioning because this will have a bug unless he does order by. And first is just as random as last so his query doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`LastOrDefault` is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN#paging-methods) in Linq-to-Entities (meaning they have not yet developed a way to translate that to the equivalent SQL code).  One option is to use `AsEnumerable` to do the ordering in memory:

```
ctx.Customers
   .AsEnumerable()
   .OrderByDescending(e => e.Purchases.LastOrDefault().DateTime);
```

However, since the order of `Purchases` is not deterministic, you may want to specify an order there as well:

```
ctx.Customers
   .AsEnumerable()
   .OrderByDescending(e => e.Purchases.OrderBy(p => p.DateTime).LastOrDefault());
```

or just use `Max` on the `Purchases':

```
ctx.Customers
   .AsEnumerable()
   .OrderByDescending(e => e.Purchases.Max(p => p.DateTime));
```

If the performance of any of those queries is not acceptable, the last resort would be to write the direct SQL and pass that to `ctx.Customers.SqlQuery()`

Comment: But this is extremely inefficient.

Comment: @FilipCordas How do you know that it would be much more inefficient than the equivalent SQL? Even if it is, what alternative to you propose?

Comment: @FilipCordas only maybe... If it's for a reasonable number of records IQueryable should be fine.

Comment: First I think this will pull every "Purchases" in a separate query if there is no include but I am not sure should be tested. But you could be right if he is pulling all the customers already this will probably be good enough.

Comment: @FilipCordas it _should_ still pull all of the customers and purchases in one query since only the ordering (not filtering) is done in-memory.

Comment: @DStanley Well you might be right I honestly don't know any more when I use EF Core things just start working in differently so I might be wrong.