# Strange results from MariaDB

Tags: join, mariadb, limit, offset

I accidentally discovered an error in MariaDB that led to unexpected results. Below are the SQL queries along with their respective outcomes:

Essentially, my objective is to retrieve data for pagination, with 10 items per page. As you can observe, I am ordering the results by the 'preference_group_id' column of the 'preference' table. However, I find it perplexing that the first result already contains preferences 5 and 6, and yet they reappear in the second result. This issue persists both with and without using DISTINCT (thus, the DISTINCT clause is irrelevant to the issue).

Upon attempting to recreate the database by importing the complete SQL file, the problem ceases to exist. The results after this are as follows

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Comment: Since I cannot reproduce the issue, I want to capture the results as evidence.

Comment: The idea is you include the queries and results as text. You can even format the latter as a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more ordering criteria.

There are two results with `preference_group_id = 1` and at least eight with `preference_group_id = 2`, presumably more.

Ordering of those sub-groups (grouped by `preference_group_id`) is undefined so you will get inconsistent results.

Try ordering by `a.id` as a secondary term...

```sql
... ORDER BY a.preference_group_id, a.id LIMIT ?, 10
```

Comment: I know how to fix the issue, but I didn't know the reason why the issue happened. Isn't MySQL using a 'virtual column' as the default for consistent results? Using 'a.id' as a secondary term is inconvenient in some contexts (e.g., when we allow users to sort the results with their expected order). As you can see, the issue is gone after I recreated the database. That means MySQL is not working consistently with the same input.

Comment: I suggest you have a read of [SQL: What is the default Order By of queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8746519/283366) and [What is the default order of records for a SELECT statement in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6051). You could be seeing insertion order which would be more consistent when recreating your DB but you simply cannot rely on it.