# Customised Ordering in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a SQL query like

```
SELECT column1,column2 
FROM table1 
WHERE column1 IN('q1','q2','q3')
```

The results are shown in the order:

```
q1
q2
q3
```

If I change the query to

```
SELECT column1,column2 
FROM table1 
WHERE column1 IN('q3','q1','q2')
```

Still the order remains same.

How to achieve this ordering in the sql statement?

Help!!

Thanks

Comment: According to your question, it looks like you want your order to be q3, q1, q2. That order is arbitrary, and not something a computer could derive without extra info, regardless of whether SQL can do it for you. Is that what you meant, or did you want descending order (q3, q2, q1)?

Comment: Are you looking for the actual alphabetical order (first statement), or are you looking for your pseudo-ordering (second statement)?  The first is achieved by almost all the answers below.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order

Comment: its actually pseudo ordering... i get the order from some other logic implemented in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to add an extra column in your table called for example 'SortOrder' that contains integers determining in which order the rows should be returned. For example, you can set SortOrder to 1 for q3, 2 for q1 and 3 for q2. The you can use the following SELECT statement to return the rows in the order you need:

```
SELECT column1,column2 
FROM table1 
WHERE column1 IN('q3','q1','q2')
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes. If only there were some way to [ORDER](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) a SQL result [BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) something.

Comment: Class, today we're going to learn about SQL. The good news is, it's mostly the select statement. The bad news is, it's mostly the select statement....

Answer (score 2):

You need an ORDER BY statement. That's the *only way* to control the order of a result set.

Answer (score 1):

Your RDBMS can't give you any guarantee that result set will be ordered by q1, q2, q3. Even if your in clause is `in('q1', 'q2', 'q3')`. If you need to enforce a particular order, use order by:

```
SELECT column1, column2 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE column1 IN('q1','q2','q3')
 ORDER BY column1
```

Also, please do include the RDBMS you are using. It might help answering the question in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

To **reverse the order of the columns**:

```
SELECT column2, column1 
FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN('q1','q2','q3')
```

To **sort the rows**, add an ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT column1, column2 
FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN('q1','q2','q3') 
ORDER BY column1 DESC
```

You can order by any column, and you can set it to ascending (`ASC`) or descending (`DESC`).

You can even sort by more than one column:

```
SELECT column1, column2 
FROM table1 WHERE column1 IN('q1','q2','q3') 
ORDER BY column1 DESC, column2 ASC
```

This would sort in descending order based on `column1` and would break ties using `column2`.

Answer (score 0):

An ORDER BY clause would help; however q1, q2, q3 or would have to be able to be sorted logically like alphabetically or if a date them by earliest to latest. That would look like this:

```
SELECT column1,column2 
FROM table1 
WHERE column1 IN('q1','q2','q3') 
ORDER BY column1 ASC
```

'or DESC if you would like the reverse
'also you can address the column in reference to its position instead of by its actual name like this:

```
SELECT column1,column2 
FROM table1 
WHERE column1 IN('q1','q2','q3') 
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```