# Change ordering based on values in WHERE statement

Tags: mysql

I am querying my table with a list of names.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE personName IN ('John','Andrew')
```

This returns 2 rows. In the table Andrew is before John.

1. Andrew
2. John

I want to order the response in the same order as in the `WHERE personName IN ('John','Andrew')`

Comment: You can never rely on selecting and ordering based on something hardcoded.  Add a field that defines the order that you want, and order by that.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I think the point of this is that the order comes from user input, not static information in the table.

Comment: Could be.  This is why I left this as a comment.  I'm simply suggesting that it's the wrong way to do it.  It should still be using a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE personName IN ('John','Andrew') ORDER BY FIELD('John','Andrew');

This is a duplicate of [Sort by order of values in a select statement "in" clause in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185029/sort-by-order-of-values-in-a-select-statement-in-clause-in-mysql) by the way.

Comment: If it's just a duplicate, flag it rather than posting an answer with a link to the duplicate. BTW, you're missing the first argument to `FIELD()`.