# how to order datas by insert sequence DESC?

Tags: sql, mysql

i has a table:TestTable, this table only has one field: value,i insert same datas:

```
value
------------
ccc
aa
111
bbb
------------
```

i run:

```
select * from TestTable
```

can show my result order by:

```
ccc
aa
111
bbb
```

now,i want get this result DESC:

```
bbb
111
aa
ccc
```

how to create this sql?

```
select * from TestTable order by (by what?) DESC
```

thak you!

Comment: Best explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order/1793162#1793162

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no automatic "creation order" identifier that could be used in an order statement. You should use an `auto_increment` column to number your records. You can then order by that column.

[MySQL docs on auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: +1 seems the only way, its not possible to inject custom sort providers into SQL - so the target sort cannot be achieved on the column in question.

Comment: any other idea? i don't have "order field" and i don't want add a auto_increment field for order

Comment: You'll have to do something like that, Zenofo. The order of the results of any select statement are undefined unless there is an order-by clause, and for that you need to have the 'right' order stored somewhere.

Comment: @Zenofo, you need to understand that the *default* order you get when **not** using `order by` is not guaranteed, so you cannot invert it..

Comment: But what about if we have application level generated primary key and not having `auto_increment` column ?

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum +1 `rank`,
       T.*
  FROM TestTable T,
       ( SELECT @rownum :=0 ) T
 ORDER BY `rank` DESC
```

Comment: Magnificent. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you want to sort using a custom sort order. Two approaches spring to mind: 1) put the sort order in a table and use that table in the query; 2) use a delimited string (assuming the number of values in the domain is small, stable and the values of similar and 'narrow' widths).

Please excuse the SQL Server syntax but fairly standard and hopefully you get the general idea:

e.g. 1

```
WITH MyTable (ID, data_col)
     AS
     (
      SELECT ID, data_col
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'aa'), 
                     (2, '111'), 
                     (3, 'ccc'), 
                     (4, 'bbb'), 
                     (5, '111'), 
                     (6, 'aa'), 
                     (7, '111'), 
                     (8, 'bbb')
             ) AS MyTable (ID, data_col)
     ), 
     MyDomainWithSortOrder (domain_col, sort_seq)
     AS
     (
      SELECT ID, domain_col
        FROM (
              VALUES ('bbb', 1), 
                     ('111', 2), 
                     ('aa', 3), 
                     ('ccc', 4)
             ) AS MyDomainWithSortOrder (ID, domain_col)
     )
SELECT T1.ID, T1.data_col, D1.sort_seq
  FROM MyTable AS T1
       INNER JOIN MyDomainWithSortOrder AS D1
          ON T1.data_col = D1.domain_col
 ORDER 
    BY sort_seq;
```

e.g. 2

```
WITH MyTable (ID, data_col)
     AS
     (
      SELECT ID, data_col
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'aa'), 
                     (2, '111'), 
                     (3, 'ccc'), 
                     (4, 'bbb'), 
                     (5, '111'), 
                     (6, 'aa'), 
                     (7, '111'), 
                     (8, 'bbb')
             ) AS MyTable (ID, data_col)
     )
SELECT ID, data_col
  FROM MyTable
 ORDER 
    BY CHARINDEX(CAST(data_col + ' ' AS CHAR(3)), 'bbb111aa ccc');
```