# select the last row in a dbase dbf file with no primary key/id column

Tags: sql, dbase

Given the following file (that I have no control over):

[image]

I want to be able to select the last row. I tried doing an ORDER BY the date column; however, as you can see there may be multiple date columns.

Without an ID field, how can I select the last column that physically exists in the file?

I've spent a while googling everything points to sorting by a column.

Comment: Last, according to what? Does it matter? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the last record physically written to the file.

Comment: Use Notepad++ (or other editor).

Answer (score 0):

As you have no clustered index (which would constitute the physical ordering of the data), it is impossible. Tables are only ordered deterministically if you use an order by clause.

See e.g. [sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793147/sql-best-practice-to-deal-with-default-sort-order)

If your current concern could still be considered in the database schema design, the adding of a loaddate field can be considered, which would be set to the time the row is created. (If your last column is such a loaddate you could still use an order by clause on the column)

Comment: As this is a dbase file, is there any way to grab the last row written in the file?

Comment: Not with the regular database functions. If this function is needed a lot, then you could consider updating the database schema according to the requirements (your needs).

Answer (score 0):

It has been awhile, but as I recall you could:

use filename
go bottom
skip -1

This should take you to the last physical record in the table.
It will not work if you have a structural index (index file with the same name as the table), I think.

The above code sample should be 3 lines, I don't know why this is appearing as 1 line.