# SQL Server 2008 - Double Click to open table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

This has probably been asked before but in the object explorer sidebar in SSMS, when you double click on a table it expands the node. I would like it to open the table. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: Yes, it kinda is but his question didn't receive a correct answer so I asked it again.

Comment: It's probably because there isn't a "correct" answer. The correct answer is to use a workaround (right-click, choose an option) or use a different method altogether (as I mention in my answer, "Open Table" / "Edit Top n Rows" is not the most scalable or well-designed feature in SSMS - see http://www.google.com/search?q=%22open+table%22+bug+site%3Aconnect.microsoft.com and http://www.google.com/search?q="open+table"+bug+site%3Aconnect.microsoft.com for a sampling of bugs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to change this behavior within SSMS alone unless you hack into SSMS and produce your own binaries.

That said, why do you want to "Open Table"? You'll notice that in 2008 this functionality has been split into Select and Edit. This is because too many people were using Open and killing their servers or holding locks when all they wanted to do was look at the data. But Edit still has a ton of bugs, and you should be very careful about using it. One was just discussed yesterday: [Why isn't my SQL query to insert a table row working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7327563/why-isnt-my-sql-query-to-insert-a-table-row-working-properly)

Comment: Well the new behavior I can understand. I just wish the double click could activate one of these behaviors by default.

Comment: Sorry, I think the answer is "no"

Comment: Ok, probably. We'll see if anyone else comes up with anything, otherwise you'll get the accepted answer.